How can I import a multisig address to my wallet?
I'm stuck on this problem since yesterday and I don't get how to fix it. How do I import a multisig address to my bitcoin-cli wallet?
I am currently doing this:
public function generateMultisigWallet($serverPubkey, $initiatorPubkey, $partnerPubkey) {
    $multisig = $this->request('createmultisig', [2, [$serverPubkey, $initiatorPubkey, $partnerPubkey], 'p2sh-segwit']);
    $multisig = json_decode($multisig)->result;

    if(!isset($multisig->address)) {
        return [false, '', ''];
    }

    $this->importMultisig($serverPubkey, $initiatorPubkey, $partnerPubkey);

    return [true, $multisig->address, $multisig->redeemScript];
}

public function importMultisig($key1, $key2, $key3) {
    $descriptor = 'sh(multi(2,'.$key1.','.$key2.','.$key3.'))';
    
    $descriptorInfo = $this->request('getdescriptorinfo', [$descriptor]);
    $descriptorWithChecksum = json_decode($descriptorInfo)->result->descriptor;

    $importData = [
        [
            'desc' => $descriptorWithChecksum,
            'timestamp' => 'now',
            "label" => "my_multisig_wallet"
        ]
    ];

    $result = $this->request('importdescriptors', [$importData]);

    var_dump("RESULT IS :");
    var_dump($result);
    return $result;
}

The problem is, I cannot get around the Error Message "Cannot import descriptor without private keys to a wallet with private keys enabled" for it, if I do not import the address I cannot get unspent UXTOs nor walletnotify works - does anybody have a solution for this? Would be extremely thankful if somebody could provide assistance.


Cannot import descriptor without private keys to a wallet with private keys enabled

This error seems to indicate that you are trying to add a watch-only address to a wallet that has private key material and Bitcoin Core doesn’t allow mixing the two.
I would suggest that you try creating a watch-only wallet: according to How to use a watch-only wallet in Bitcoin Core?, you can create a wallet with "disabled private keys" from the wallet creation menu, and the RPC documentation for createwallet indicates that you can do it from the command line by calling
bitcoin-cli createwallet "wallet_name" true
where the second argument is disable_private_keys:


disable_private_keys    (boolean, optional, default=false) Disable the possibility of private keys (only watchonlys are possible in this mode).



Thanks for clarifying this - i found the solution, thanks! Unfortunately i can still not implement an active descriptor for a wsh(multi)) descriptor (so multisig).
If i do delcare a range, it shows "Range should not be specified for an un-ranged descriptor" - if i do not declare a range it says "Active descriptors must be ranged".
Really struggling with it, ugh.

@zbder: Sorry to hear that. Could you please start another topic for that one? I think it would be easiest addressed if it were a new question.
